# What does ARIMA(2,1,1) mean?

Tags: r

I used auto.arima to forecast in my time series data set, and let the auto.arima function be arima.model. Then I typed in the console arima.model and it showed these values:

```
Series: train.data$M4 
ARIMA(2,1,1) 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2      ma1
      0.2138  0.0284  -0.9424
s.e.  0.0493  0.0482   0.0260

sigma^2 estimated as 6.9:  log likelihood=-1361.02
```

Id like to know what does 2,1,1 mean? Is that P,D,Q? same with coefficients. Im not that good in both R and ARIMA so Id like to know. Thank you so much.

```
Id
AIC=2730.03   AICc=2730.1   BIC=2747.42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,You are correct.(2,1,1) is p,d,q found by auto.arima process using given Information criterion.which means you have 2 AR terms,1 difference and 1 Moving average term in your series.